# The aura component implementing the "forceCommunity:themeLayout" interface is not being fully reloaded during navigation

Tags: community, aura, custom-theme-layout

**BACKGROUND**

I'm implementing the Salesforce Lightning Community.
I have 2 community pages with 2 different custom layouts (implementing the `forceCommunity:themeLayout` interface).
I'm facing the issue related to the reloading of the Theme Component during the next redirection during pages.

---

**PAGE A**

`Page A` is using the `Theme A` theme component and the following components are added to the `Content` section in the Community Builder:

- Component X
- Component Y
- Component Z

The `Theme A` component has the `{!v.Body}` placed inside the `aura:if` block that checks the condition.

- If the condition is `true` then display body and stay on the current page
- If the condition is `false` then redirect from `Page A` to `Page B`

---

**PAGE B**

`Page B` is using the `Theme B` theme component.

The `Theme B` component is checking the same condition (as `Theme A`) but the behavior is different:

- If the condition is `true` then redirect from `Page B` to `Page A`
- If the condition is `false` then stay on the current page and display the button that can change the condition to `true` and redirect to page `A`

---

**ISSUE**

1. User enters `Page A` - the condition is `false` so the `v.Body` is hidden by `aura:if`
2. User is being redirected to `Page B` - the condition is `false` so the button to change the condition is being displayed
3. User clicks the button - the condition is being changed to `true`
4. User is being redirected to `Page A` - the redirection spinner is still running, the `init()` event of the `Theme A` **is not being called** again, the page is not being loaded. User needs to refresh the page manually and then the condition is `true`, `Page A` is being loaded correctly.

---

**QUESTIONS**

- Any ideas why the `Theme A` is not being fully reloaded during navigating back to the page that is using that?
- Any ideas on how to force re-load of this component?
- IMO it's related to the `v.Body` placed inside the `aura:if` on the `Theme A` - can it be replaced with something?